# how do i display or retrieve the whole table(New to struts and weblogic and servlet)?

Tags: java, sql, weblogic, struts

im new to struts and weblogic. i made a sample code, and cant move on cause i cant get the result that i wanted.

The code should be just simple: retrieve all records in the database and display it on the web browser.

[The DB table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40o66.png) <-- Table name is LOC_LOG

---

my .jsp (main_log.jsp)

```
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>main_log</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <table border = '1'>
  <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Remarks</th>
  </tr>
<s:iterator value ="locatorEntity_list">
<tr>
        <td class="eename" align="center" style="font-weight:bold">
            <s:property value="eename" ></s:property>
        </td>
        <td align="center" style="font-weight:bold">
            <s:property value="remarks"></s:property>
        </td>
 </s:iterator>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Apparently, the code doesn't go inside the iterator and only got this as a [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t16BX.png)

i have a deduction that the problem might be in my action method but i dont know what is the problem itself. i hope anyone can help me..

ill also include what is in my action method

```
private String eename;
private String remarks;
private List<locatorEntity> locatorEntity_list;

public String retrieve_logdata(){
    locatorEntity logs = new locatorEntity();
    logs.setEename(this.getEename());
    logs.setRemarks(this.getRemarks());
    List<locatorEntity> locatorEntity_list = locatorDAOFacade.qry_getLog(logs);
    
    Iterator<locatorEntity> lon_itr = locatorEntity_list.iterator(); 
    List<locatorEntity> temp_list = new ArrayList<locatorEntity>();
    while(lon_itr.hasNext()){
        locatorEntity inside_while = new locatorEntity();
        inside_while = lon_itr.next();
        inside_while.setEename(logs.getEename());
        inside_while.setRemarks(logs.getRemarks());
        temp_list.add(inside_while);
      }
    
    this.setLocatorEntity_list(temp_list);
    
return SUCCESS;
}
```

---

qry_getLog

```
<resultMap  id = "qry_getLogMap" class = "entity.locatorEntity">
    <result property="eename" column="EENAME" />
    <result property="remarks" column="REMARKS" />
</resultMap>

<select id="qry_getLog" resultMap="qry_getLogMap" parameterClass="entity.locatorEntity">
SELECT
    EENAME,
    REMARKS
FROM
    LOC_LOG
</select>
```

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd strongly recommend sticking to Java naming conventions (classes `CamelCased` with leading capital, non-static vars `camelCased` with leading lower-case, no underscores). Sticking to this convention makes your code easier for Java devs to read.

Comment: If the code doesn't go to iterator, then probably you've not elements in the list.

Comment: @DaveNewton i cant get to display the records in the table